# Editting Attributes of selected OptionButton VBA

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button

I'm trying to make a grid of Option Buttons from about 10x60 and would like to do so with VBA, but I can't get the attribute changing to work.

So far I got this:

```
Sub Buttons()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
k = 48
For i = 8 To 9
    For j = 5 To 15
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("OptionButton" & k)).Select
        k = k + 1
        Selection.Copy
        With Sheets("Weekreview")
            .Cells(i, j).Select
            .Paste
            .Shapes.Range(Array("OptionButton" & k)).Select
            .OptionButtons(k).GroupName = i - 1
            .OptionButtons(k).LinkedCell = Range(j, i)
        End With
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that the program errors at .OptionButtons(k).GroupName with the message "Unable to get the OptionButtons property of the Worksheet class". 
Anyone who can help me?

Edit 1: My first try (before I tried pretty much all the ways I could find googling the issue) was to use Selection.GroupName, this didn't work either. It looks like it can't access the attributes. So either the attribute changing is wrong, or the selection is wrong.

Edit 2: I got the entire program working except the changing of the GroupName of an existing OptionButton. Even though Selection.LinkedCell works, Selection.GroupName doesnt.

Comment: I suspect that the option button `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("OptionButton" & k)).Select` doesn't exist. Take a look at this thread and see how far it can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702443/need-help-looping-through-groups-of-option-buttons-while-copy-past-cell-contents

Comment: I've tried a lot of different ways. I know there is a function called OptionButtonName.GroupName, but I cant fill in a variable like k (i.e. "OptionButton" & k.GroupName). And for the link, I do get what they are doing there, but I just want to edit one specific button, and not cycle through them.

Comment: Your post doesn't make clear what you want to do. Do you wish to set the group name for existing option buttons? Or do you intend to add option buttons to existing (or not existing) groups? Either way, you can't use the Selection object.

Comment: What I want to do is edit an Option Button's GroupName attribute with visual basics, the rest of the program works now. Somehow you can do "Selection.LinkedCell" but not "Selection.GroupName"

Answer (score 0):

Your code copy and paste `OptionButton & k` then refers to `OptionButton & k+1` (object doesn't exist). 
Look at line were k is incremented:

```
k = k + 1
```

Comment: It does look that way, but when copy-pasting an option button, it will just cycle. So when copying 48, it will paste 48, but that specific button will have id=49. So the k+1 is actually necessary. When I try to run the program, it will create a button with id 49 but fail to edit attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Please change all the words

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("OptionButton" & k))
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Option Button " & k)
```

Comment: Doing this will make it so the program won't be able to find the specific Option Button because they are named "OptionButton1", not "Option Button 1"

Comment: Did you try this code? ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("OptionButton" & k)

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error as before "unable to get the optionbuttons attributes"

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code:

Sub Buttons()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer        

    k = 48
    For i = 8 To 9
        For j = 5 To 15
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("OptionButton" & k)).Select                
            k = k + 1
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            With Selection
                .Name = "OptionButton" & k
                .Top = Worksheets("Weekreview").Cells(i, j).Top
                .Left = Worksheets("Weekreview").Cells(i, j).Left
                .GroupName = i - 1
                .LinkedCell = Range(j, i)
            End With

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not allowing me to edit the groupname, the positioning, name, and linkedcell do work though. So it's still giving the same error.

Comment: The GroupName is worksheet name as default. I think would be great if you can shared your Excel file here.

Answer (score 0):

Controls with a naming convention of TypeName# are ActiveX controls (e.g.  "OptionButton1","TextBox1").  The object itself is wrapped in an OLEObject. ActiveX controls on a Worksheet should be references using the Worksheet's **OLEObjects** collection.

Properties not available directly from the OLEObject can be access by the `OLEObject.Object`.

[image]

[image]
    Sub Buttons()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim opt As OLEObject
        Dim cell As Range

```
    With Sheets("Weekreview")
        For Each cell In Range(Cells(8, 5), Cells(9, 15))
            Set opt = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Width:=108, Height:=21)
            With opt
                .Left = cell.Left
                .Top = cell.Top
                .Width = cell.Width
                .LinkedCell = cell
                .Name = cell.Address(False, False)
                With opt.Object
                    .GroupName = cell.Row
                    .Caption = cell.Address(False, False)
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```